# CDI Servlet java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

People, please, help me!!! I am driving really crazy. My code have been working before today, and now it's broken...

Here is my servlet:

```
@Stateless
class TempSession {
    void createFile( String fileName ) {
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter( fileName );
            writer.close();
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@WebServlet( name = "CreteFileServlet", urlPatterns = "/createCSV" )
public class CreateCSVConfigurationServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    TempSession session;

    protected void doPost( javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response ) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {}

    protected void doGet( javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response ) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        session.createFile( "d:/session.txt" );
    }
}
```

Here is web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CreateFileServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.bs.amg.test.servlets.CreateCSVConfigurationServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CreateFileServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/createCSV</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

JSP snippet:

```
<form action="createCSV" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Create configuration"/>
</form>
```

Anв Jboss 7.0.1 log server snippet:

```
14:10:52,471 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "ear-1.0.ear"
14:11:10,336 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/web].[CreteFileServlet]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet CreteFileServlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bs.amg.test.servlets.CreateCSVConfigurationServlet.doGet(CreateCSVConfigurationServlet.java:136) [classes:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

Please, I really need your help!!!!!

Comment: Use your VCS to know which changes have been made to go from "working" to "not working".

Comment: Check what is done in CreateCSVConfigurationServlet.java ligne:136

Comment: @GuyBouallet I'm 99% sure that is referencing the doGet in the first code snippet...

Comment: I know the fault, and it is beacuse "session" is not initialize! I knew it, and I want you to tell me, why CDI-container didn't initialize my "session" variable???!!! It must be working!!!

Comment: Don't you need a producer for TempSession?

Comment: @Guy Bouallet, producer? Sorry, I didn't get it. Can you explain?

Comment: Do you have the proper `beans.xml` files in the archive that contains the servlet and the archive that contains the EJB? Meaning the WAR, or if the servlet is in a JAR in `WEB-INF/lib`, that JAR and so on...

Comment: I see that you are using direct injection. So no producer required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the injection is not occuring because CDI is not enabled. Make sure you have a beans.xml as stated in CDI documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html. Here is a sample beans.xml file you can use to enable CDI:

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Comment: yes, I have this file in my resources/META-INF. But now meanwhile deploying Jboss gives me: "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS016060: Could not resolve CDI bean for injection point com.test.servlets.TempSession com.test.servlets.CreateCSVConfigurationServlet.session with qualifiers []"

Comment: omg....damn it... Men, I am so sorry, I really appologise and appreciate your attention and help. I am trully stupid programmer. My fault was becase I defined TempSession in the same file as my servlet was.... This is a very mistake.... Thx for all!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring your servlet with both webservlet annotation and web.xml mapping. You should have only one declaration using the annotation as in [this](http://hudson.jboss.org/jenkins/job/JBoss-AS7-Docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/guides/developer-getting-started-guide/target/docbook/publish/en-US/html/helloworld.html) example.